# Multiple Instances of Namespace Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, namespaces

I have some namespace utilities that I want to create multiple instances of, but can't seem to get it working.

My module looks like:

```
Project.utilities.gallery.position = (function() {

// WILL CREATE THE BUBBLES FOR THE SLIDESHOW AND WILL THEN MOVE THEM AUTOMATICALLY AFTER BEING TRIGGERED

var slide_container, position_container;    
var create = function(_container) {//this function will be responsible for creating the bubbles for the slideshow

    if (typeof _container == "undefined"){
        return false;
            }

    slide_container = _container.children('.content');      
    slide_container = _container;
};

var update = function() {//this will be responsible for updating the slideshow!     
    console.log(slide_container);
};
```

When I try to do something like

```
var test = Project.utilities.position;
test.create("hello world from test");

var test_2 = Project.utilities.position;
test_2.create("Hello world from test_2");

test.update() // outputs "hello world from test_2", not "hello world from test"
```

How can I do this so it works properly?

Comment: What happens when you run the code as-is? And, unrelated: you'll probably get more help if you go back and accept the answers to your previous questions. :)

Comment: thanks for the tip, relatively new to stack overflow and didn't know this!

Comment: when I run test.update() it will act like test_2, so it seems these are both referencing the same "object" but I want to create two seperate instances

Comment: I knew you were new, it's cool. Stand-up guy.

Comment: Check this out, though: I think this is the answer to your problem. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript

Comment: thanks for the help. I just need to make sure it was a function, not a self-executing function

Comment: Your included code is not complete.  We're missing the end of it.